After I push my first project up I get error " ERROR Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies"
This is my first attempt to create a Nuxt 3 application on Heroku with client and server functionality. I am developing on windows and  When i run the npm run build and npm run start all is fine locally.The error log from Heroku says " ERROR  Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies" I have no idea what this is,I have also tried specifying the version of node in the package.json file as 22.12 and rebuilding npm but still get the error after i push the application. Any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks.
